# Angular Template Syntax - reference an input field's 'name' using ngFor index

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-template, angular-forms

I'm creating input fields using an ngFor index. I have a custom validator directive `myValidator` that returns a key `validatorFailed` if the field's validation fails.

`<div *ngFor="let ma of moviesArray; let i = index">`

```
    <input
      name="ma{{i}}"
      myValidator
    />
```

I know that to throw a validation error, I need to do something like this:

`<div class="validation-text" *ngIf="ma{{i}}.errors?.validatorFailed">'Field validation failed.'</div>`

But it doesn't work because I think there's something wrong with calling `errors` on `ma{{i}}`. How do I correctly reference the input field name `ma{{i}}`?

Comment: No, you wouldn't use that. Instead, you would 1. use ngModel, 2. use a template variable `#foo="ngModel"`, 3. Use `foo.hasError('customKey')`. You can do the same inside the ngFor.

Comment: what does ma look like? ['one', 'two']?

Comment: @JBNizet Thanks for the answer. Doesn't seem to work though. The fields don't render

Comment: @SoEzPz moviesArray = ['one', 'two', 'three'], so `ma` would be 'two' for example.

Comment: Post your code. Don't force us to guess what could be wrong. Stackblitz is your friend.

Comment: So ma is a string then? Like JB is mentioning, we need to know what ma is, share an example.

Comment: @SoEzPz Here's a simple stackblizt example: 

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jjj3ci

I'm trying to throw a validation error when user enters more than 5 characters in the input field. What am I doing wrong here?
All my code is in "mydir.directive.ts" and "app.component.html"

Comment: Your stackblitz doesn't use ngModel, doesn't have a template variable, defines a directive but doesn't use it anywhere, doesn't have any ngFor. Please, read my comment again, and the angular guide about forms.

Comment: @JBNizet I tried adding `#abc = "ngModel"` but it gives me an error, even though I added FormsModule to my imports. I added my directive to the input field. I'm trying to keep it simple, that's why I didn't add the ngFor yet

Comment: If you don't use the ngModel directive, your input is ignored by Angular. It won't add any validator to it. This is really fundamental stuff. Read the guide.

Comment: JB is right; also what you are doing wrong is using Angular when you really only want to use HTMl and javascript. Read https://angular.io/guide/forms or https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms and do what they say if you are going to use angular. Then recreate your stackblitz and we'll checkout what you learned.